# PHP PDO add edit update select statments

Tags: php, pdo

These are my `PDO` add, edit, delete ,select functions for my MVC pattern implementation.

I need to know if this implementation is correct using `PDO`.

These are Model Class functions:

```
   public function getStudentById($id){

        $stmt       = $this->db->con->query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = '$id'");
        $result     = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $result;

    }

    public function addStudent($arrData){

        $sql        = " INSERT INTO student (name,age,address)".
                      " VALUES ('$arrData[name]','$arrData[age]','$arrData[address]')";

        $stmt       = $this->db->con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $this->db->con->lastInsertId(); 

    }

    public function editStudent($arrData){

        $sql        =   " UPDATE student SET ".
                        " name='$arrData[name]',age='$arrData[age]',address='$arrData[address]'".
                        " WHERE id=$arrData[id] ";

        $stmt       = $this->db->con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $this->db->con->lastInsertId(); 

    }


    public function deleteStudent($id){

        $stmt       = $this->db->con->query("DELETE FROM student WHERE id = '$id'");

    }
```

Comment: Use placeholders for arguments

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0):

Correct or not, you can do it easier and safer. One of the main advantages of PDO is the support of parametrized queries, where you only write placeholders and let PDO insert the values. This will help protecting against SQL-injection, because PDO will do the correct formatting for you.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = ?';
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); // or PDO::PARAM_STR
$statement->execute();
```